# Java Merge arraylists with pattern

Tags: java, arraylist, merge

I have two arrays with different Objects.

```
ArrayList<Array1> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Array2> array2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to merge these arrays to

```
ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
```

with pattern, for every 3-4 item in array1, add item in array2.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not enough information: what is you assumption about the list sizes ? What do you want to do with elements that were not added ? ignore them ?

Comment: *"How can I do this?"* You write some code. Well, first you decide whether it's 3 or 4, i.e. complete the specification of what you intend to do. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Just a side note, it's quite a bad idea to name an arraylist as array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep things simple and just use a loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < array1.size(); ++i) {
    array.add(array1.get(i));
    if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) {
        array.add(array2.get(i/4));
    }
}
```

The logic of the above loop is that each iteration always adds an item from `array1` to the final list.  In addition, after adding 4 items from `array1` it adds an item from `array2`.

I have assumed here that `array2` has enough elements to support covering the enitre `array1` list.  Should you plan on doing this in production, you might want to check for this edge case.